# Using flex with a form

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7nncyky/)

Im trying to use flex to position the submit button at the bottom of the right hand column.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <form>
            <input type="text"/>
            <input type="submit" class="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot get the form element to stretch to the height of it's parent though.

Also on a side note, what will happen on IE9, will the submit button just sit beneath the input? ie. will the flex stuff just be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/90gmxukk/).

Assuming that you would like to apply flex on the two columns, then apply flex on the form itself so that the submit button will be aligned at the bottom.

As for IE9 support, I'm not sure, I do not have that browser, just remove the `display: flex;` property from the CSS and that is what it would probably look like.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <form>
            <div>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div id="submitHolder">
                <input type="submit" class="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
}
.left {
    flex: 1 0;
    background: gold;
}
.right {
    height: 100%;
    flex: 1 0;
    background: pink;
}
form {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background: grey;
}
form > div {
    flex: 1 0;
}
#submitHolder {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you will need to use nested flex containers since flex box targets direct child elements and not grand child elements.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  background: gold;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  background: pink;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  display: flex; /* Add for nested flex container */
}
form {
  background: grey none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: flex; /* Nested flex container */
  width: 100%;
}
input {
  align-self: flex-start; /* Align the input to the starting of the form element */
}
.submit {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <form>
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="submit" class="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `flexbox` all the way around. You'd have to find alternatives for IE9 etc.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  background: gold;
  height: 400px;
  flex-grow: 1; 
}
.right {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
form {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.submit {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <form>
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="submit" class="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```